# How to restrict imports to TS files under a folder (especially React)

Tags: eslint, lint, typescript-eslint

I have a React project that's getting large, but I'm not ready to split into submodules . So I'd like the folder structure to reflect what will eventually be a spinoff package.

As I'm working with that setup I'd like to constrain the allowed `imports` to that sub folder, to especially not import `React`, so it'll be easier to split apart when the time is right.

example

```
/src
   /ui  #import React freely
   /core #Don't allow React to be imported
```

```
// /core/request.ts

import React from 'react';  // Lint Error, cannot import React under this folder!

...
<code>
...
```

and if it did, it would show a lint error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Underrated question! Any solution on this matter? Restricting imports feels like a very important feature also for restricting import of components that should only be used with wrappers

Answer (score 0):

In your .eslintrc.json you can set override rules like this

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["src/core/**/*.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
          "paths": [{
            "name": "react",
            "message": "Direct import of React is not allowed in the src/core folder."
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```